# Batch Programming: Self Sufficient Self-Destructing Files

Tags: batch-file

I've tried creating a GIF photo that is set from a batch file to self destruct after 10 seconds, then using CMD's copy function to "embed" the batch file into the GIF, but when the GIF is opened, it doesn't work, although the batch file works as expected without being "embedded". Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong to achieve that?

This is the batch file code.

```
@echo off
ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 > NUL
del "example.gif"
start /b "" del "%~f0" ^&exit /b
exit
```

Comment: `del` is not a standalone command, to use it with `start`, you'd have to invoke `cmd.exe`, as it's internal to it. For the [tag:batch-file] self deletion, you need, `Start /B Cmd /C Del "%~f0"&Exit /B`, however I prefer, `(GoTo) 2>NUL&Del "%~f0"`.